# Create array of not pre-determined size inside a structure

Tags: c++

I want to work with Images, and I want to create my structure Image with first 2 values to be it's size (grayscale) and the third - data (2D array of size m by n).

How can I implement it? If I don't know the image's size in advance. Something like this:

```
struct Image{
    int n;
    int m;
    data = 2D array of size mxn
}
```

Comment: Using a `std::vector<>` is most probably the best way you could go, though your question is too unclear about your exact requirements to be answered appropriately, and being helpful for future research.

Comment: By the way, maybe you want to use *constructor*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead I would use

```
struct Image{
    int n;
    int m;
    vector<vector<int>> data;
}
```

Of you could use a 1D vector that has size

```
vector<int> data(m * n);
```

Comment: Really? Wouldn't it be a lot easier to use a one-dimensional vector?

Comment: Possibly. I suppose it would depend on their intended use of the vector.

Comment: @Cyber ... also, shouldn't this be `vector<vector<uint8_t>>`, or so?

Comment: Which libraries are required here? And how can create variables of this type in the main program, if the size of such type is not determined?

Comment: @МихаилМихайловичГенкин without knowing exactly what you want to do, a very common image library in C++ is [`OpenCV`](http://opencv.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring encapsulation, something like this could work:

```
#include <vector>

struct Image {

    int n;
    int m;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data; // May want to change int type ?

    Image(int n, int m) : n(n), m(m), data(n) {
        for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
            data[row].resize(m);
        }
    }
};

// Example Usage
Image img(10, 10);

for (int row = 0; row < img.n; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < img.m; col++) {
        img.data[row][col] = valueFromImageFile;
    }
}
```

If you're not just looking for something quick and dirty, and this is going to be an ongoing project, I would recommend that you learn more about object oriented concepts :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two common patterns for that (even if inherited from C). Both share a common principle : a logical separation between a fixed size header and a variable part.

First method : the struct contains the fixed size part and a pointer (or pointers in a generic case) to memory allocated with new (in constructor) and deallocated in destructor. It is a bit *hand-driven*, but easy to use and to understand.

Image could look like (I assume `Pixel` is a class representing a single pixel):

```
class Image {
private:
    int _x, _y;
    Pixel *data;

public:
    Image(int x, int y);
    ~Image();

    Pixel& getPixel(int i, int j) {
        return data[i * _y + j];
    }
};

Image::Image(int x, int y) {
    data = new Pixel[x * y];
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
}

Image::~Image() {
    delete[] data;
    data = NULL;
}
```

Second method : the pseudo-struct is composed of a fixed size header, and of a dynamic part. The dynamic part is declared in the struct to be of size 1. It is obviously false, and you cannot use `sizeof` on such a struct, but as C does not inforce comparison of array to the declared size it works :

```
class Image {
private:
    int _x, _y;
    Pixel data[1];
    Image(int x, int y); // private to force usage of createImage

public:
    static Image* createImage(int x, int y);

    Pixel& getPixel(int i, int j) {
        return data[i * _y + j];
    }
};

Image* Image::createImage(int x, int y) {
    Image* image = (Image *) malloc(sizeof(Image) + (x * y - 1) * sizeof(Pixel));
    image->_x = x;
    image->_y = y;
    return image;
}
```

I must admit it is really C code embedded in C++, but I cited it because it is heavily used in Microsoft Win32 API.